# How to add fields to 'content' format in Views

Tags: 7, views, comments

I created a view from  node. In the FORMAT settings, I choose content (because I need to display the comment form). How do I add fields such as post date or Share this link ([ShareThis module](https://drupal.org/project/sharethis)) to the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps:

First you need to configure *"share this"* module:

Go to Configuration >> Web services >> Sharethis (admin/config/services/sharethis)

select the **Node Types** where you want to use this.

[image]

Then go to content type manage display settings and in custom display settings check the modes which you have used in view.

[image]

That's it.

Comment: Thanks! Any solution for the post date?